# How to find 3 triangles passing through every dot of a 5x5 grid in z3

Tags: python, z3, solver, smt, z3py

[image]

I am trying to learn to use Z3 in the old smt solver variant, as thats what I will be studying in school in the near future. Having said this, a solution or clues in Z3 python would also be appreciated.

Comment: The typical way to solve such puzzles in SMT is to write a checker to a proposed solution. That is, think about how you'd "validate" a given solution is correct. Then, by the magic of constraint solving, z3 will get you a solution from that checker. Think about how you'd represent this problem, and how you'd write a checker. Note that stack-overflow works the best if you show what you tried and what problems you faced, instead of asking for solutions directly.

Comment: yeah, ik, but i have spent a couple of days now, and I genuinely have no idea where to start.

Comment: Go in stages:  First write a program that detects a straight line. Then write a program that detects a triangle. Then write a program that detects three disjoint triangles that cover all the nodes. For the final step, you can take three lists of inputs, and apply your previous functions to make sure all are triangles, and that they cover all the nodes.

Comment: Turns out while this is doable in z3, it's not what I would recommend as a first learning project. It requires a few techniques that is not easy to express using the Python interface. In case it helps, I coded it up using Haskell's SBV bindings; which allows you to script z3 in Haskell taking advantage of the high-level programming features afforded by the latter. Hope it helps: https://gist.github.com/LeventErkok/4fddbac1c731575b0596c8f4799eecce

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```py
    from z3 import *
    
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70565942/how-to-find-3-triangles-passing-through-every-dot-of-a-5x5-grid-in-z3
    
    s = Solver()
    n = 7
    triangles = 4
    Cells = range(n * n)
    N = range(n)
    Triangles = range(triangles)
    corners = 3
    Corners = range(corners)
    
    
    #  triangles have three grid points each;
    #  row and column values are kept in two vectors
    Trow = [IntVector("tr" + str(t+1), corners) for t in Triangles]
    Tcol = [IntVector("tc" + str(t+1), corners) for t in Triangles]
    
    #  save some [] typing        
    def Row(t, c):
        return Trow[t][c]
    
    def Col(t, c):
        return Tcol[t][c]
    
    def ShowTriangle(model, t):
        print()
        print("Triangle " + str(t+1))
        for e in Corners:
            row = model.eval(simplify(Row(t, e)+1))
            col = model.eval(simplify(Col(t, e)+1))
            s = "col " + str(col).ljust(4) + "; row " + str(row).ljust(4)
            print(s)
        for row in N:
            s = ""
            for col in N:
                if model.eval(IsOnTriangle(n-1-row, col, t)):
                    s = s + str(t+1)
                else:
                    s = s + "."
            print(s)
    
    
    def InInterval(x, a, b):
        return And(x >= a, x <= b)
    
    #  a grid point is covered by a given triangle, if it is located
    #  on an edge of the triangle
    def IsOnTriangle(row, col, t):
        return Or(IsOnEdge(row, col, t, 0, 1),
                  IsOnEdge(row, col, t, 1, 2),
                  IsOnEdge(row, col, t, 0, 2))
    
    def IsOnEdge(row, col, t, c0, c1):
        row0 = Row(t, c0)
        row1 = Row(t, c1)
        col0 = Col(t, c0)
        col1 = Col(t, c1)
        #  for the time being, we disregard skewed edges
        return Or(IsOnHorizontalEdge(row, col, row0, col0, row1, col1), 
                  IsOnVerticalEdge(row, col, row0, col0, row1, col1),
                  IsOnMainDiagonalEdge(row, col, row0, col0, row1, col1),
                  IsOnSecondaryDiagonalEdge(row, col, row0, col0, row1, col1))
    
    def Equal3(x, a, b):
        return And(x == a, x == b)
    
    def IsOnHorizontalEdge(row, col, row0, col0, row1, col1):
        return And(Equal3(row, row0, row1), 
                   InInterval(col, col0, col1))
    
    def IsOnVerticalEdge(row, col, row0, col0, row1, col1):
        return And(Equal3(col, col0, col1), 
                   InInterval(row, row0, row1))
    
    def IsOnMainDiagonalEdge(row, col, row0, col0, row1, col1):
        return Or(And(row0 < row1, 
                      col0 < col1, 
                      (row - row0) == (col - col0), 
                      (row1 - row) == (col1 - col), 
                      InInterval(row, row0, row1), 
                      InInterval(col, col0, col1)), 
                  And(row0 > row1, 
                      col0 > col1, 
                      (row - row1) == (col - col1), 
                      (row0 - row) == (col0 - col), 
                      InInterval(row, row1, row0), 
                      InInterval(col, col1, col0)))
    
    def IsOnSecondaryDiagonalEdge(row, col, row0, col0, row1, col1):
        return Or(And(row0 < row1, 
                      col0 > col1, 
                      (row - row0) == (col0 - col), 
                      (row1 - row) == (col - col1),
                      InInterval(row, row0, row1),
                      InInterval(col, col1, col0)), 
                  And(row0 > row1, 
                      col0 < col1, 
                      (row - row1) == (col1 - col), 
                      (row0 - row) == (col - col0),
                      InInterval(row, row1, row0),
                      InInterval(col, col0, col1)))
    
    #  every grid position has to be visited by at least one triangle
    for row in N:
        for col in N:
            s.add(Or([IsOnTriangle(row, col, t) for t in Triangles]))
    
    # delimit triangles to grid
    for t in Triangles:
        for e in Corners:
            s.add(Row(t, e) >= 0, 
                  Row(t, e) < n, 
                  Col(t, e) >= 0, 
                  Col(t, e) < n)
    
    #  enforce order of corners
    #  to reduce symmetries
    for t in Triangles:
        for e in range(corners-1):
            s.add(Row(t, e) <= Row(t, e+1))
    
    #  enforce order of triangles
    #  to reduce symmetries
    for t in range(triangles-1):
        s.add(Row(t, 0) <= Row(t+1, 0))
    
    if sat == s.check():
        print("sat")
        for t in Triangles:
            ShowTriangle(s.model(), t)
    else:
        print("no solution found!")
```

Resulting output for 4 triangles in a 7x7 grid:

```
sat

Triangle 1
col 1   ; row 1   
col 7   ; row 1   
col 1   ; row 7   
1......
11.....
1.1....
1..1...
1...1..
1....1.
1111111

Triangle 2
col 2   ; row 2   
col 7   ; row 2   
col 2   ; row 7   
.2.....
.22....
.2.2...
.2..2..
.2...2.
.222222
.......

Triangle 3
col 7   ; row 3   
col 3   ; row 7   
col 7   ; row 7   
..33333
...3..3
....3.3
.....33
......3
.......
.......

Triangle 4
col 2   ; row 3   
col 6   ; row 3   
col 6   ; row 7   
.....4.
....44.
...4.4.
..4..4.
.44444.
.......
.......
```

As commented by @alias, this is probably not suitable for a first `Z3` exercise.
My model won't find solutions with triangles where the edges are skewed (neither horizontal, nor vertical, nor diagonal).
Adding symmetry breaking constraints helped to speed-up the search for the 7x7 case.

---

A similar model written for [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/):

```
int: n = 5;  %  grid dimension
set of int: N = 1..n;
int: triangles = 3;
int: corners = 3;
set of int: Triangles = 1..triangles;
set of int: Corners = 1..corners;

%  triangles have three row/column grid points each.
array[Triangles, Corners] of var 1..n: Row;
array[Triangles, Corners] of var 1..n: Col;
    
%  a grid point is covered by a given triangle, if it located
%  on an edge of the triangle
function var bool: IsOnTriangle(N: row, N: col, Triangles: t) =
    IsOnEdge(row, col, Row[t, 1], Col[t, 1], Row[t, 2], Col[t, 2]) \/
    IsOnEdge(row, col, Row[t, 1], Col[t, 1], Row[t, 3], Col[t, 3]) \/
    IsOnEdge(row, col, Row[t, 2], Col[t, 2], Row[t, 3], Col[t, 3]);
    
function var bool: Equal3(N: x, var N: a, var N: b) =
    (x == a) /\ (x == b);
    
function var bool: IsOnEdge(N: row, N: col, var N: aRow, var N: aCol, var N: bRow, var N: bCol) =
    IsOnHorizontalEdge(row, col, aRow, aCol, bRow, bCol) \/
    IsOnVerticalEdge(row, col, aRow, aCol, bRow, bCol) \/
    IsOnDiagonalEdge(row, col, aRow, aCol, bRow, bCol);
        
function var bool: InInterval(N: x, var N: a, var N: b) =
    if x >= a then x <= b else x >= b endif;
    
function var bool: IsOnHorizontalEdge(N: row, N: col, 
                                      var N: aRow, var N: aCol, 
                                      var N: bRow, var N: bCol) =
    Equal3(row, aRow, bRow) /\ 
    InInterval(col, aCol, bCol);

function var bool: IsOnVerticalEdge(N: row, N: col, 
                                    var N: aRow, var N: aCol, 
                                    var N: bRow, var N: bCol) =
    Equal3(col, aCol, bCol) /\ 
    InInterval(row, aRow, bRow);
   
function var bool: IsOnDiagonalEdge(N: row, N: col, 
                                    var N: aRow, var N: aCol, 
                                    var N: bRow, var N: bCol) =
    InInterval(row, aRow, aCol) /\
    InInterval(col, aCol, bCol) /\
    (IsOnMainDiagonalEdge(row, col, aRow, aCol, bRow, bCol) \/
     IsOnSecondaryDiagonalEdge(row, col, aRow, aCol, bRow, bCol));

function var bool: IsOnMainDiagonalEdge(N: row, N: col, 
                                        var N: aRow, var N: aCol, 
                                        var N: bRow, var N: bCol) =
    ((aRow < bRow) /\ (aCol < bCol) /\
    ((row - aRow) == (col - aCol)) /\
    ((bRow - row) == (bCol - col))) \/ 
    ((aRow > bRow) /\ (aCol > bCol) /\
    ((row - bRow) == (col - bCol)) /\
    ((aRow - row) == (aCol - col)));     
 
function var bool: IsOnSecondaryDiagonalEdge(N: row, N: col, 
                                             var N: aRow, var N: aCol, 
                                             var N: bRow, var N: bCol) =
    ((aRow < bRow) /\ (aCol > bCol) /\
    ((row - aRow) == (aCol - col)) /\
    ((bRow - row) == (col - bCol))) \/ 
    ((aRow > bRow) /\ (aCol < bCol) /\
    ((row - bRow) == (bCol - col)) /\
    ((aRow - row) == (col - aCol)));     
                
%  every grid position has to be visited by at least one triangle
constraint forall(row in N, col in N) (
    exists([IsOnTriangle(row, col, t) | t in Triangles])
    );

%  prune symmetries to speed-up the search

constraint forall(t in Triangles) (
    forall(e in 1..corners-1) (
        Row[t, e] <= Row[t, e+1]
    )
);

constraint forall(t in 1..triangles-1) (
    Row[t, 1] <= Row[t+1, 1]
);

output [ "\nTriangle \(t): \(Col[t, c]);\(Row[t, c])" | t in Triangles, c in Corners];
```